# Comparison of lists - remove elements

Tags: java, list, removeall, remove-if

My question is - How to remove objects from the list by comparing it with the second list.

List1 - The first list contains **email addresses**. 
List2 - The second list contains only domains in the format **"@domain.com"** etc

I would like to delete objects (e-mails) from the first list which is **NOT** on the second list (List2 - domains).

For example:
If List1 contains the email address "email@domain.com" and the second List2 does **NOT** contain "@domain.com" - then I want to delete this email address (from list 1)

I know it may be duplicated post: 
[Remove objects from list - contains strings - Comparing the List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817109/remove-objects-from-list-contains-strings-comparing-the-list)   
But I don't know how to create a negation (!) of these answers...

I will be grateful for your quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817249/1682559) in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817109/remove-objects-from-list-contains-strings-comparing-the-list), you'll just have to change the `anyMatch` to `noneMatch`:

```
list1.removeIf(email -> list2.stream().noneMatch(email::endsWith));
```